# ``Quantum''/ non-commutating extension of polytopes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry, quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry

Are there non-commutative (ie. quantum) extensions of polytopes?

More specifically I was wondering if there are some deformation, say $\hbar$, to polytopes which when is taken to be zero, one gets back the original polytopes. References involving simple polytopes (e.g. associahedra/Stasheff polytopes) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question would make much more sense (and perhaps have reasonable answers) if you [edit] it to tell us what you might use such an extension for. Why is this an interesting question?

Comment: You mean like combinatorial polytopes or do you need to have it embedded in some quantum space? In any case, I don't think so, but I would be interested in your motivation to find some. For the combinatorial side, there is the theory of *quantum graphs*, which were introduced only recently and are quite intensively studied these days. So, you might start with the graphs of polytopes. Let me point you to my article, where I introduce anticommutative hypercubes ($q$-deformation for $q=-1$ essentially) https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13618